# no results for fetchRequest predicate though %@

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I have troubles to apply a filter to my core data fetch request. I already checked other posts dealing with the correct implementation of the *predicate* functionality, but somehow it does not work for me.

I researched the net and I figured out to use **%@** for strings. This is what I did since title (the attribute from entity ITEM) and nameIdentifier are both of data type string.

Maybe I missed something changed for swift 3?

This is my code:

**swift 3**

```
func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {

 nameIdentifier = textField.text

    // save to Entity
            let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<ITEMS> = ITEMS.fetchRequest()

    // check if string has correct value
            print ("NameIdentifier: \(nameIdentifier)") 

            fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "title == %@", nameIdentifier)
            do {
                if let results = try context.fetch(ITEMS.fetchRequest()) as? [ITEMS] {
                    for object in results {

    // check: results of the predicate fetch requests
                            print ("Results: \(object)")
                        }
                    }
                }catch {print ("no results")}
}
```

However, the result in my console is not filtered at all. It fetches all data that is already stored:

**console output**

```
NameIdentifier: test1

no results <RISK_ITEMS: 0x6000002a63c0> (entity: RISK_ITEMS; id: 0xd000000001c40000 <x-coredata://7687B389-1346-4C27-9B93-99B324FC28D2/RISK_ITEMS/p113> ; data: {
    "title" = test1;
})
no results <RISK_ITEMS: 0x6000002a3120> (entity: RISK_ITEMS; id: 0xd000000001c80000 <x-coredata://7687B389-1346-4C27-9B93-99B324FC28D2/RISK_ITEMS/p114> ; data: {
    "title" = test2;
})
```

Comment: You are executing the wrong request, it should be `context.fetch(fetchRequest)`.

Comment: Awww, yes you are so right! Thanks a lot! That did it...